# Soap Call to http automatically tries to connect via https

Tags: php, apache, soap, soap-client, soapfault

When making a SOAP call to a http:// address it is automatically trying to connect via https://  I need to force SOAP to only connect via http:// is there a way to do this?  I have ensured MultiViews is not enabled in Apache.

I have even tried to do a simple SoapClient call without encapsulating it into a class, with the login included in the initial call.

```
$soap = new \SoapClient('http://gotouri?wsdl, array(
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'userpass',
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' = 1
    )
);
```

this is the SOAP-FAULT error I receive:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://www.do...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0)`

Anyone have any ideas how to force the soap-client to use http?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason it was automatically parsing https://. In the XML file on the server, the location address is to https://

```
<service name="MagentoService">
<port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
<soap:address location="https://www.thisguyssoapserver.com/index.php/api/soap/index/"/>
</port>
</service>
```

Thus, my localhost SSL isn't working correctly.  I do not know whether a self-signed certificate would enable me to make this call or not, however I can make a successful soap call after pushing the code to a lamp server on gcloud.